# Storing price with tax included

Tags: decimal

I have a cash register system where there is a price and tax field. The price is entered WITHOUT tax (as customary in the United States).

For some people in Europe they like to include tax within the price. Example:

Include tax 30.00
tax percent 10%

In order to store the price without tax, the price would be:
27.2727273

The problem is, in my system I only allow for 2 decimal points of the price.

Is the best way to do this to increase the number of decimal points allowed for the price field and calculate the price without tax for UK customers and store it?

How many decimal points will I need?

Answer (score 1):

If we are talking about currency you need more the two decimal point accuracy.  I would say you need at least 4 decimal point accuracy for the simple fact. 1/100 of a cent and 1/1000 of a cent given enough transactions CAN be a good sum of money

> Is the best way to do this to increase the number of decimal points
>   allowed for the price field and calculate the price without tax for UK
>   customers and store it?

The solution to your problem is to store 3 numbers.

- Price of the item without Tax.
- Amount of Tax
- Total Price with Tax

This would allow you to store the same information for any item, for any customer, all that matters is how they input and/or display the price.

Sadly, this was a little long for a comment, and since there is no code I can't supply any.

Comment: Displaying accurate prices - with and without tax - is usually a key business requirement, and rounding issues mean that doing the calculation on the fly often leads to weirdness. This is the only way I know to stay sane...

Comment: "_27.27 + 10% tax is only 29.97_" No, 27.27 + 10% is 29.997. That's $0.003 or 0.3 _cents_.

Comment: @Widor - That might be the case but after 10,000 sales its also $30.00

Comment: Yes, but you can't round all 10,000 individual transactions as one - the rounding has to take place at the point it happens in the real world, which is when the individual customer pays. Now, if one customer buys 10 units in one transaction then you'd round to $272.73 (not $272.70). Rounding and gaining/losing a cent here and there is a common problem in accounting.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is not to store the amount of tax at all.

Store a *rate* of tax with applicable from/to dates, and derive the amount of tax wherever needed by applying that rate to the price. This will also make your like a lot easier when that tax rate changes (as the UK VAT rate did not so long ago).

For the actual price, you should be able to get away with 2 decimal places, as the rounding will be applied to each transaction, because they take place in the "real world" - i.e. nobody pays £6.66-and-two-thirds, it will be rounded to £6.67.

If you're trading in something other than discrete physical items (oil, foreign currency, shares) then yes, you'll need to have the ability to record fractions of the lowest monetary denomination.

Comment: I do store the rate, I wasn't clear in question. I store the unit_price and tax_percent. But if they want to sell for 30.00 (including tax) with 10% tax, the unit price needs to be 27.2727273 for the math to work out.

Comment: @ChrisMuench In that case, the price wouldn't be `27.2727...`, it would be 27.27 and the tax would be 2.73.

Comment: 27.2727273 * 1.10 is $30, the price is $30.00 including tax so I worked backwards